# Is it possible to prevent a USB storage device from being read by a PC?

Tags: usb-storage

I was wondering if a USB storage device like an external hard drive or memory stick could prevent the OS from reading or writing to it?

To give an example where this could be used:

My portable hard drive is connected to my laptop and I make a quick run to the bathroom, before I leave I unmounted the hard drive but leave it plugged in. Someone comes whilst I'm gone and attempts to access the data on it but can't because of a data block of some sort, this would include them plugging it out and back in or trying it on another PC. When I come back all I need to do is a simple action to authenticate myself and I can go back to accessing my data.

What I'm trying to ask if this is possible by either using hardware or software that runs on the hard drive? I want to avoid installing any software on a PC and instead focus on the USB device itself, possibly modifying a hard drive to perform such a function.

This is for project where I'm attempting to give access to storage device based on the distance between the device and the key (which in this case is a smartphone). The Phone would be able to notify the user if they stray too far away from the device (suitable settings would be provided to disable that).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: sounds like you need a USB storage device with encryption and a quick means to wipe the active key

Comment: Wouldn't encryption happen as a result of software? I was thinking of something similar to a write blocker used in forensic investigations but able to prevent reading as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are external hard drives on the market that provide hardware encryption (which makes it OS and software independent). Those can be combined with simple RFID authentication. So you can lock or unlock the drive by simply putting your key tag on it. One example is S.M.A.R.T. Lock by Digittrade, but there are many out there.